# Convert Dimention name values into key values in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2008, ssas-2012, mdx-query

I have two questions:

1. My date dimention values are names instead of key. Is it possible to display key values for the date dimention in MDX. I know I can go inside the dimention and change the property of attribute to display key value instead of name. But I want to query the data without making any changes. My below MDX query is what I am trying:

   select [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on columns,
   non empty
   [Ship Date].[Date].[Date] on rows
   from [Mycube]
2. How to get maximum date along with its amount. I am using filter function. The below query is still returning all records even after using filter function:

   select [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on columns,
   non empty
   filter([Ship Date].[Date].[Date],tail(nonempty([Ship Date].[Date].[Date], 
   [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])).item(0).item(0).MEMBER_KEY) on rows
   from [Mycube]

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Have you tried `Member_Key` property for #1 ?

Comment: yes ..it gives error.. "The MEMBER_KEY function expects a member expression for the 1 argument. A level expression was used."

Comment: Just use tail for 2

Comment: #1, try to use this `[Ship Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Member_Key` as new calculated member and put it in a set near Amount. Use Date hiararchy as is.